# How do I get Counts/Flag correctly using case expressions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with fields and values that look like this.

```
CustomerID    OrderMedium     NumberofOrder
101             Computer           5
101             Phone              2
102             Computer           9
103             Computer           1
103             Phone              6
104             Phone              2
105             Computer           3
105             Phone              3
```

From the above table, I am trying to create another table with fields CustomerID, OrderMedium, OnetoFiveOrders, SixtoTenOrders, Count.

The customerID field should contain the CustomerID, OrderMedium field should contain the OrderMedium, OnetoFiveOrders should contain a flag of 'Y' if a customer has between one to five orders, SixtoTenOrders should contain a flag of 'Y' if a customer has between Six to Ten orders, and count should contain the Number of Orders.

So for example, CustomerID 101 with an OrderMedium of Computer will have a flag of 'Y' under OnetoFiveOrders and count of 5 since they have 5 orders.

The problem I'm having is that if the same customer with a different Order Medium has a total order count that is greater than 5 then it should have a flag of 'Y' under SixtoTenOrders, but still give the number of order for that medium

So For Customer 101, the table should look like this.

```
CustomerID    OrderMedium     OnetoFiveOrders   SixtoTenOrders     Count
101             Computer           Y                                 5
101             Phone                                Y               2
```

Since the customer has a total Order count of 7, it should give a flag of 'Y' under SixtoTenOrders and a count of 2 because they have 2 orders under the Phone Order Medium.

I'm having problems getting my code to work/output this way and would appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

This is my my code so far:

```
Select CustomerID, OrderMedium, NumberofOrder as Count, case when               NumberofOrder between 1 and 5 then 'Y' else
case when NumberofOrder between 6 and 10 then 'Y'
else null
end as OnetoFiveOrders
end as SixtoTenOrders
from CustOrder;
```

Comment: Why are there "Y"s in different columns for customer 101?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the "Y" in columns based on the total order count for the customers, then use analytic functions:

```
Select CustomerID, OrderMedium,
       (case when sum(NumberofOrder) over (partition by CustomerId) between 1 and 5
             then 'Y' 
        end) as OnetoFiveOrders,
       (case when sum(NumberofOrder) over (partition by CustomerId) between 6 and 10
             then 'Y' 
        end) as SixtoTenOrders
,   NumberofOrder as Count
from CustOrder
order by CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an Oracle instance right now, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    OrderMedium,

    CASE WHEN NumberOfOrder BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL AS OneToFiveOrders,
    CASE WHEN NumberOfOrder BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL AS SixToTenOrders,

    CASE WHEN NumberOfOrder BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN NumberOfOrder - 5 ELSE NumberOfOrder AS OrderCount

 FROM CustOrder
 GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderMedium;
```

I will point out that this will be VERY SLOW if you're dealing with a large table, since it has to scan the whole thing.  Consider breaking it down into several statements in that case.